# Python requests_ntlm import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Hello i am receiving the following error when i try to import the requests_ntlm package. I installed the package with easy_install requests-ntlm. I am trying to use this library so that I can log onto an aspx.net webserver with www-authenticate: negotatiate NTLM response header using python. Appreciate any help solving this issue let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SHS.py", line 2, in <module>
    from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\requests_ntlm\__init__.py", line 1, in <module
>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\requests_ntlm\requests_ntlm.py", line 4, in <m
odule>
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\__init_
_.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler  # noqa
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\HTTPNtl
mAuthHandler.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import ntlm
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\ntlm.py
", line 25, in <module>
    from . import des
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\des.py"
, line 19, in <module>
    from . import des_c
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\des_c.p
y", line 19, in <module>
    from .des_data import des_SPtrans, des_skb
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\des_dat
a.py", line 25, in <module>
    U32(0x00820200), U32(0x00020000), U32(0x80800000), U32(0x80820200),
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm3-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm3\U32.py"
, line 32, in __init__
    value = six.byte2int(value)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg\six.py", line 605, in
byte2int
    return ord(bs[0])
TypeError: 'long' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Try running it from another directory.  It looks like you're running it from the directory you built requests_ntlm in which might be causing issues when python searches for the modules to import.

Comment: It gives the same error running it from the python cmd as well. The directory is an empty directory with the only the py file in it.

Comment: This is especially confusing because there is no bdist egg file for requests_ntlm on PyPI. Can you provide the contents of `SHS.py`?

Comment: Shs.py consists of one line. Just importing the requests_ntlm library

Comment: Well I can't reproduce this. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while connecting to SharePoint using SSO(Single Sign-On)
The following statement solved my problem:

```
pip install requests_ntlm
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that! Package maintainer here.

It looks like it was a problem with Windows. I just released v1.0.2 which fixes this and added Appveyor support to catch these problems in future.

**Edit:** On a Windows PC you probably hit the error with `pip HttpNtlmAuth` to fix it you will need to `pip requests_ntlm` to get v1.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, however:

I've opened a GitHub issue for this bug: https://github.com/trustrachel/python-ntlm3/issues/6 .

Currently the workaround is to use `requests-ntlm` version 0.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this problem when I am on

```
Python 3.7.0
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
```

Finally SOLVED with different version

```
Python 3.7.0
requests-ntlm==0.1.0
```